# How to make a sort from a fits table python

Tags: python, numpy, astropy

I own a table in fits format. I am using the astropy.io.fits library in Python.
I'm reading the file and I would like to print my array with conditions.

For exemple, I want to print all rows where the column "CHI" > value

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8

from astropy.io import fits
import numpy as np

        ##################################
        # Fichier contenant le champ 169 #
        ##################################

file = '/astromaster/home/xxxx/Bureau/Stage/Champs/Field_169/Field169_combined_final_roughcal.fits'

field169 = fits.open(file)          # Ouverture du fichier à l'aide d'astropy

tbdata = field169[1].data           # Lecture des données fits

#print tbdata['CHI']
#print tbdata[tbdata['CHI'] < 1.0]

for row in tbdata :
    if tbdata['CHI'] < 1.0 :
        print row
```

And, how is it possible to add one or two more conditions in the new printed array ?

Thanks !

Comment: Just to clarify something that none of the other answers really did--there's nothing in your question that's particular to the fact that the data came from a FITS file, or even particular to Astropy really.  Your question is just about basic manipulation of Numpy arrays--the core data type for numeric arrays in Python.  See my comment here from the other day: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673564/operations-on-column-length#comment59079189_35673564

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Astropy's fits interface functionality is best for working with image data, rather than tabular.

The [Astropy tables](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/) library will be helpful to you. Using `t = astropy.table.Table.read(fname)` (aside: `file` is reserved in Python, so you should avoid using it as a variable name) will allow you to read in a FITS table as an Astropy table, which works a lot like a `numpy` record array.

You can then filter based on column values, e.g.: `print t[t['CHI'] < 1.]` (If you aren't familiar with numpy, you might do some more reading on masking and element selection, since this is essentially identical to numpy's functionality--if you aren't familiar, I think of reading the above statement "`t` such that `t['CHI']` less than 1.")

You can combine conditions, as well: `print t[(t['A'] < 1) & (t['B'] > 2)]`. And when you're done, you can write out using `t.write(fname2)`

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer, I will use your method ;)
I will come back if I have errors yet

Comment: If I just print my array, is it possible than it takes lot of time because I've 3 millions of rows ?

Comment: Yes, having 3 million records will likely slow things down. But you're basically always better off selecting like I showed over looping (since arrays are optimized for selection operations).

Answer (score 2):

Well first of all and that's unrelated to your question: If you open any file you should either close it again afterwards or use it as context manager. I usually prefer the context manager:

```
filename = '...'
with fits.open(filename) as field169:
    tbdata = field169[1].data
... continue without indentation after you have finished with the file.
```

Afterwards you have a record numpy array, you can use it but since structured numpy arrays are more tables a true table program like `pandas` or `astropy.table` might be very convenient.

But if you really want to confine yourself to the table you get `from fits.open` (you shouldn't though because the recarray and structured array behave a bit different than normal table operations) you can use what is given in the [documentation](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/usage/table.html#table-operations):

```
mask = tbdata['CHI'] < 1.0
tbdata[mask]
```

or if you want to have multiple conditions just add them with the `&` (if both should apply) or `|` (if at least one of the conditions should apply):

```
mask = tbdata['CHI'] < 1.0 & tbdata['CHI'] > 0.5
tbdata[mask]

mask = tbdata['CHI'] < 1.0 | tbdata['OTHER'] > 0.5
tbdata[mask]
```

I hope this helps you. But probably you are better off using @DathosPachy answer with tables.

Comment: @Andromedae93 - No problem. Please note that if you find any answer particularly helpful upvote it and accept the answer that best solves your problem. See also [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: @MSeifert makes a really good point about file-handling. I'm definitely guilty of forgetting it, and not using it is (generally) a mistake, especially when large files are concerned.

Comment: I edited my code and it's working well !
I used your method, that's to say by using masks.

Unfortunately, the syntax with "&" doesn't work (I've an error message). So I code step by step with tbdata_temp.

I don't know if it's possible to upload my code in this part or if I need to answer my post ? In order to show you if the code is good with the syntax ^^

Comment: To be clear, in a simple script like this explicitly closing a file or using a context manager isn't really necessary, but it's a good habit to get into anyways.  File management, especially with FITS files, is something a lot of novice programmers don't pay enough attention to (often to performance detriment).